# Sourdough teacakes/hot cross buns?

Tags: baking, bread, sourdough

I've made sourdough before and I'm just making my sponge and I wondered if it was possible to make sourdough hot cross buns/tea cakes? Would it be to heavy too rise or would it not taste right?

Thanks in advance!

NB: don't know whether you have tea cakes in the US but in the UK they are small buns containing currants and/or sultanas and peel eaten at tea or breakfast (toasted with butter).

Comment: Sebiddychef, as it stands, you are directly requesting for recipes which is not allowed. I think your question with the recipe request omitted is sufficient and will most likely get you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I've added sourdough starter to things like pancakes and waffles, but never hot cross buns. However I believe it would be very tasty as the sourdough would take some of the sweetness of the buns. I found this link about sourdough hot cross buns and thought it might be along the lines of what you were looking for https://sourdough.com/recipes/one-penny-two-penny